# UTF Hebrew Letter Encoding issue with ASP.Net MVC on Mono

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, ubuntu, utf-8, mono

I feel I'm a bit in over my head on this one.  I have developed an ASP.Net MVC website for a friend that allows them to paste in Hebrew words and it does some conversion/translation.  I am using MySQL as a data backend with ASP.Net MVC 5.

The website is fairly simple.  The database consists of two tables which store letters, and translations.  I am using MySQL EF6 for data access layer.  There are basically three screens on the website, one for managing each table, and one for doing the translations.

When I run it in my development environment (VS 2017/Windows 10), everything works as expected.  I can edit data using the Hebrew Unicode characters and they save properly to the database.  Here is an example:

[image: Hebrew Screenshot 1]

When I click Save, I expect those values to be saved to the database, and they work fine. However, I have recently converted the website to run on a Mono/Ubuntu environment for hosting.  I got the environment setup using mod_mono and Apache2. Everything is working perfectly, except when I save a page like this, the Hebrew character א gets converted into a question mark (?):

[image: Hebrew Screenshot 2]

Here's what I've determined so far.

- I know Apache/MySQL is setup properly to handle these values, because the data *displays* fine.  It only gets messed up when I save it.
- I am also running PhpMyAdmin on the same server, and when I modify that same row through the table editor, it does *not* mess up the encoding.
- I've tried adding the Default Encoding utf-8 to the Apache configuration with no luck.
- I've tried adding globalization with default encodings of utf-8 to web.config and it didn't help.

How do I troubleshoot where the value is getting messed up?  Is there a simple solution I need to apply to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

- The bytes to be stored are not encoded as utf8/utf8mb4. Fix this.
- The column in the database is `CHARACTER SET utf8` (or utf8mb4). Fix this.
- Also, check that the connection during reading is UTF-8.
- HTML forms should start like `<form accept-charset="UTF-8">`.

For more discussion, see [Trouble with utf8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)

If that is not enough to solve your problem, find the `HEX`, as discussed in "Test the data" in that link; then ask for more help.